# How to return an instance based on its parent using Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

We have been using Windsor Castle as our DI Container but we are looking around for alternatives. Now I got to the Simple Injector and so far I have been impressed by its simplicity but one scenario I am stuck at right now is when we are using late bound instantiation for some of our components.

My first question is, is it even possible?

With Windsor it is done like this;

```
Container.Register(Component.For<ILogger>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(
        (kernel, componentModel, context) => new Logger(
            context.Handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.Name));
```

Is there a way to do the same with Simple Injector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Simple Injector, you will just have to either:

1. Register a Func delegate explicitly using `Register<Func<A, B, C>>((a, b) => { ... })`
2. Create an interface such as `ILoggerFactory`, creste an implementation and register them.

**UPDATE**

After reading your question again and looking up the definition of Castle's `UsingFactoryMethod` I came to the conclusion that I misinterpreted your question. What you are looking for is creating an instance based on its parent type: [Context Based Injection](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Context_Based_Injection).

You can achieve this by implementing the [Context Based Injection Extension method](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContextDependentExtensions&referringTitle=Advanced-scenarios) that is given as example on the Simple Injector's documentation wiki.

When you add this extension method to your project you can do the equivalent registration as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterWithContext<ILogger>(context =>
{
    return new Logger(context.ImplementationType.Name);
});
```

Comment: I don't think I really understand how you mean with alt 1. The second alternative... well, I do want my logging to indicate what class that is actually logged but I do not wish to register one and each of the loggers in a factory. I actually tried the RegisterWithContext implementation but there is also the scenario where we need to use the servicelocator pattern... :-( and that is not resolving then.

Comment: @Per: I'm sorry. I just realized I totally misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. I hope this answers your question. Please let me know when it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you did but your earlier answer led me in the right direction. I actually implemented the RegisterWithContext. My only problem is that I under some circumstances need to pick up the implementation with ServiceLocator pattern and by then I have no ImplementationType and I need to set a default name instead. It does work :-) Thanks