# Simple Injector: Registering a type with constructor argument that's based on its parent

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I am currently in the process of removing Ninject from my project, and moving to using Simple Injector but there is one thing that I can not get working properly.

For my logging, in the registering of services, I was previously able to pass in a parameter into my logging class as such

```
_kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("name",
        x => x.Request.ParentContext.Request.Service.FullName);
```

I am looking for a way to recreate this in Simple Injector.  So far I have everything else working but this.  I can get the logging to work, albeit without having the correct logger names being shown, by doing the following:

```
_container.Register<ILogger>(() => new Logger("test"));
```

Anyone got any experience in doing anything similar?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675137/how-to-return-an-instance-based-on-its-parent-using-simple-injector

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That registration is a form of *context based injection*. You can use one of the `RegisterConditional` overloads for this.

`RegisterConditional` however does not allow the use of factory methods to construct a type. So you should create a generic version of your `Logger` class, as follows:

```
public class Logger<T> : Logger
{
    public Logger() : base(typeof(T).FullName) { }
}
```

You can register it as follows:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ILogger),
    c => typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Transient,
    c => true);
```

But please do read [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892137/windsor-pulling-transient-objects-from-the-container) (and my answer) and question yourself if you aren't logging too much.

Answer (score 5):

[Context based injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection) is now supported in Simple Injector 3 by using the `RegisterConditional` method. For example to inject a Logger into Consumer1 and a Logger into Consumer2, use the RegisterConditional overload that accepts a implementation type factory delegate as follows:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ILogger),
    c => typeof(Logger<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Transient,
    c => true);
```